# Can alias in SQL Server contain slash?

Tags: sql-server, alias

I'm not sure if there is such a question that I can't seem to find. I have a clustered instance named FC\SQLSRV. Because this is the virtual name so I can't create an alias for the clustered instance. I have another SQL Server database server (B) using the default name instance (MSSQLSERVER). What I want is to create the alias for the server B using the same clustered instance name. The reason is I just want to switch my application (that is connecting to the server B) to use the clustered instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a client alias on the application server. You will have to run CLICONFG.EXE on the client, click add on the alias tab, click TCP/IP add the server alias B and set the connection paramters to be FC\SQLSRV after this all connections to server B from that client/application server will be forwarded to FC\SQLSRV If your application is 32bit you will also have to do the same for the 32bit registry and run %systemroot%\syswow64\cliconfg.exe

[image: ClientAlias]